# Timeout while installing javascript chaincode on Raspberypi 4 8gb arm64

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to run a blockchain network on raspberry pies using Hyperledger fabric.
Arm64 architecture is not supported, therefore I tried using community binaries and docker images.

```
comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 034 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.0.0.3:36576 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5m0.006349555s
[endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 035 finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 300000ms channel= txID=4406cd5d
[endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 036 failed to invoke chaincode _lifecycle, error: timeout expired while executing transaction
```

This happens from simply calling

```
peer lifecycle chaincode install ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz
```

Does anyone have maybe experienced with the same topic(installing JavaScript chaincode on raspberry pi) or can maybe know the reasons for such an issue with fabric.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons installing the chaincode takes more than 5 min, I tried it 3 consecutive times and in the end it worked, and I used a new docker image for the fabric nodenv that I built myself.[alix40/fabric-nodeenv](https://hub.docker.com/r/alix40/fabric-nodeenv)